# Linking dependencies with Gradle 6.5 in a Kotlin Multiplatform Multimodule project

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-multiplatform

I have the following structure and i want to include `integration-jvm-1` as a dependency inside `module-mp-1` and inside `application-jvm-1`, i want to include `module-mp-1`'s JVM output as dependency.

See the sample project on Github:
https://github.com/JVAAS/kotlin-multiplatform-multi-module-setup

Here's the overview of what i've done so far:

```
generic-project
  +-- applications
      +-- application-jvm-1
  +-- integrations
      +-- integration-jvm-1
  +-- modules
      +-- module-mp-1
  build.gradle.kts
  settings.gradle.kts
```

my `build.gradle.kts` is empty, `settings.gradle.kts` is as follow:

```
rootProject.name = "generic-project"

include("applications:application-jvm-1")
include("modules:module-mp-1")
include("integrations:integration-jvm-1")

pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap")
        }
    }
}
```

`applications/application-jvm-1/build.gradle.kts` is as follow
(note the `api(project(":modules:module-mp-1"))` dependency)

```
plugins {
    val kotlinVersion = "1.4-M2"
    application
    kotlin("multiplatform") version kotlinVersion
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version kotlinVersion
}

group = "com.generic.applications"
version = "1.0.0"

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = uri("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap")
    }
    maven {
        url = uri("https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx")
    }
    gradlePluginPortal()
}

kotlin {
    jvm {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {

        val serializationVersion = "0.20.0-1.4-M2"
        val coroutinesVersion = "1.3.7-1.4-M2"

        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
                implementation(kotlin("reflect"))

                api(project(":modules:module-mp-1"))

            }
        }
        val jvmTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
            }
        }
        all {
            languageSettings.enableLanguageFeature("InlineClasses")
        }
    }

}

application {
    mainClassName = "Application"
}
```

`integrations/integration-jvm-1/build.gradle.kts` is as follow:

```
plugins {
    val kotlinVersion = "1.4-M2"
    kotlin("multiplatform") version kotlinVersion
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version kotlinVersion
}

group = "com.generic.integrations"
version = "1.0.0"

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = uri("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap")
    }
    maven {
        url = uri("https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx")
    }
    gradlePluginPortal()
}

kotlin {
    jvm {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {

        val serializationVersion = "0.20.0-1.4-M2"
        val coroutinesVersion = "1.3.7-1.4-M2"

        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
                implementation(kotlin("reflect"))

                // logging
                val slf4jVersion = "1.7.25"
                val logbackVersion = "1.2.3"
                implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:$slf4jVersion")
                implementation("org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:$slf4jVersion")
                implementation("org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:$slf4jVersion")
                implementation("org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:$slf4jVersion")
                implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logbackVersion")

            }
        }
        val jvmTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
            }
        }
        all {
            languageSettings.enableLanguageFeature("InlineClasses")
        }
    }

}
```

`/modules/module-mp-1/build.gradle.kts` is as follow:
(note the dependency `api(project(":integrations:integration-jvm-1"))`)

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4-M2"
}
group = "com.generic.modules"
version = "1.0.0"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url = uri("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap")
    }
}
dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test-junit5"))
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))

    // ktor
    val ktorVersion = "1.3.1"
    //implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-cio:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-html-builder:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-html-jvm:0.7.1")

    // logging
    val slf4jVersion = "1.7.25"
    val logbackVersion = "1.2.3"
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:$slf4jVersion")
    implementation("org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:$slf4jVersion")
    implementation("org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:$slf4jVersion")
    implementation("org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:$slf4jVersion")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logbackVersion")

    api(project(":integrations:integration-jvm-1"))

}
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>() {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
}
```

When i pull Generic Project into IntelliJ and do a gradle refresh, i'm not getting error, but i'm also unable to get it to compile when i use module dependencies inside application

```
import com.generic.modules.Module1 <<-- unresolved reference modules

object Application {

    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {

        println("TEST")

        println(Module1().toString())

    }


}
```

Any ideas?
I've made a sample project on Github with all of the above
https://github.com/JVAAS/kotlin-multiplatform-multi-module-setup

If this directory structure is making it more difficult than it should be, then i'm happy to change that too. Just want dependencies working one way or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Building Multiplatform Projects with Gradle](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html) is the best resource on this topic. Specifically in [Adding Dependencies](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html#adding-dependencies) it says:

> a `project('...')` dependency on another multiplatform project is resolved to an appropriate target automatically. It is enough to specify a single `project('...')` dependency in a source set's dependencies, and the compilations that include the source set will receive a corresponding platform-specific artifact of that project, given that it has a compatible target.

The article also contains examples on how to configure project dependencies.

Comment: that's pretty cool that there's docs inside the Kotlin docs, i was digging through the Gradle docs which covers gazillions of different ways of doing irrelevant stuff.
let me work through those docs tonight, thanks for the link!

Comment: You're welcome. IMHO the Kotlin multiplatform plugin developers slightly abused the flexibility of Gradle to implement a DSL that looks like vanilla Gradle but in reality is not. That definitely makes it hard to search for documentation, as you'd inevitably end up in the Gradle docs and wonder why what's described there doesn't work with the KMP. Sorry for the rant!

Comment: I seem to be making progress, but not 100% there yet, i'm missing something small somewhere to get it to compile. Have updated my question and made a github sample project
https://github.com/JVAAS/kotlin-multiplatform-multi-module-setup

Comment: I noticed that you're not using the `kotlin("multiplatform")` plugin in `modules:module-mp-1` and yet your code is in `commonMain`. The `commonMain` is a source set declared by the multiplatform plugin, `kotlin("jvm")` doesn't treat that directory as a source set. You should either declare that source set explicitly, or rename `commonMain` and `commonTest` to just `main` and `test`.

Comment: Submitted PR fixing the above mentioned issues, plus a few other ones.

Comment: You changed the Multi Platform Module to JVM only, i changed it back (need that module to be multiplatform so it generates JS as well) and fixed a bunch of stuff, got it running now in IntelliJ now with the multimodule part. Gradle Build is still failing with unresolved reference.

Comment: Got it working, had a PEBKAC error :-D
Thanks for the help